# Really basic primer questions: Should we add them?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking about questions like:

- What is a Schema?
- What is a Blueprint?
- What is a Component?
- What is a Template Building Block?
- How do I create a Component?

Are these questions we want on the site?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please don't try to *seed* common questions on this site… ***especially* so early in this site's development.** I try and convey this to every new site we launch, but

**your home page says a lot about your site.**

If you are asking the simple, basic questions copied out of the pages of a user manual somewhere, you are going to have trouble attracting experts.

Please, at least read

[**Your New Site: Asking the First Questions**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/)

**The folks coming to visit your site will have those simple questions soon enough.** When users visit this site, they expect questions to represent actual problems asked in good faith from those who are actually seeking the help… But let *them* ask them.

Questions should come organically from those with genuine need.  If it starts to look like the authors don't actually need help, the whole site starts to look a bit contrived and perhaps even a waste of time.

Let's not seed content here, particularly in these earliest days.

Comment: +1 and fair enough. I like the idea of *allowing* basic questions as opposed to adding them ourselves. And I still get to ask my "how can I tell what type of item this is?" question. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I think we must *answer them when they pop up*. It hurts my brain, but sometimes I do try to go back to when I didn't understand Tridion at all and these were the type of questions I had (OK, maybe not "what is a schema"), but definitely basics like "Why can't I create a child publication".

Of course we all want the super advanced questions and caching techniques, but it usually takes an implementer 1 to 2 years before they start asking themselves those advanced questions...

Comment: I guess we should make sure the basics are only explained once and that we redirect (or even close) any question that is just a repeat of such a basic question. Strict Moderation

Comment: I think I misread Rob's question. Instead of "should we add them" I read "should we not downvote them into oblivion", and it's in that context that I say "we must".

Answer (score 2):

We could also just follow the flow and wait for them to be asked by our newer community members.

If all goes well this site is here to stay, so we don't need to start setting it up by what we think should be there, but we can just answer the real questions ppl have and mark basic questions as a protected wiki article like explained here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but I'd recommend grouping such "basic" questions so they're easy to find and don't hurt Nuno's brain too much. We can also add details to clarify context.

For example:

- What are the Tridion item types (building blocks) and how can I recognize them in the CME or code? Do they have specific identifiers or types?
- What is the minimum I need in order to publish content to a website? I created a schema and a corresponding component and nothing happens when I publish. ;-)
- How do I create a component in ***_*__** API?

Ideally we'd stick with the expert questions that focus on real, practical questions we have.

I think the challenge is getting us and others into a habit of asking (appropriate questions) here instead of on Skype, via email, or out loud to the rubber duck or SDL buddy on the desk (well you still can, but please bring the knowledge back here).