# Let's get critical: May 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tridion Stack Exchange](http://tridion.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

---

#### Results

Thanks to everyone who participated in this! This community is still small but strong and growing, with all signs pointing to a bright future ahead for it. Keep up the good work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Is there a way to add a Service Reference to the Core Service without using Tridion.CoreService.Client.dll?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/593/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-service-reference-to-the-core-service-without-using-trid)

  **Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Get Page Filename from Core Service GetListXml](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/661/get-page-filename-from-core-service-getlistxml)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 10, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Tridion UGC doesn't save anything in database](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/494/tridion-ugc-doesnt-save-anything-in-database)

  **Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [CWA migration 1.5.04 to CWA 2011](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/631/cwa-migration-1-5-04-to-cwa-2011)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Publish Binary File in a MM Link Field](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/685/publish-binary-file-in-a-mm-link-field)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 6)
- [Storing/Getting the name and email address of the user in a variable who submitted the comment](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/842/storing-getting-the-name-and-email-address-of-the-user-in-a-variable-who-submitt)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 4)
- [Get a list of all schemas for a publication, including inherited ones via core service](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/444/get-a-list-of-all-schemas-for-a-publication-including-inherited-ones-via-core-s)

  **Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [IFunctionSource functions for DWT in Razor?](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/792/ifunctionsource-functions-for-dwt-in-razor)

  **Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Updating component field while publishing does not publish the latest version of component](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/484/updating-component-field-while-publishing-does-not-publish-the-latest-version-of)

  **Net Score: 5** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Cache configuration with single-server deployer and web application](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/557/cache-configuration-with-single-server-deployer-and-web-application)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 2)

Answer (score 3):

I've went through a round of 10 Site Self-Evaluation questions and gave most `excellent` or `satisfactory`.

One fascinating point is these including some great questions, even when the answers weren't what the asker was expecting. These Q&A give background context and summarize approaches we've seen or done before all in one place!

### Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not?

No, with several coming from StackExchange, I think we have strong habits to encourage and promote better questions. You will see us ask for more details, re-tag questions, and discuss on how to deal with questions on the meta site (as seen in "[How strict should we be on the Q&A format?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1/46)").

Here are examples of our proactive disucssion, where we ask and decide on an approach that fits this community even before we have "problem" questions. We're even working out the finer details of taxonomy approach (which probably reflects our collective experience with content management).

- [What should the FAQ Contain?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3/46)
- [Really basic primer questions: Should we add them?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23/46)
- [Tags and Terms for Types of Workflow?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/124/46)
- [Should deployment be a synonym for content-delivery?](https://tridion.meta.stackexchange.com/q/114/46)

### Questions or answers that could use an edit?

Like above, we continually edit our own and others' questions and even discuss coding guidelines. ;-)

**We could probably vote a bit more and make sure we're using consistent phrases and including enough details to make the Q&A sets SEO-friendly.**

### Anything that's going really well?

I'm seeing new users and long-time Tridion subject matter experts joining in. You can tell the excitement and support for Tridion Stack Exchange by blog posts, the links from SDL TridionWorld, and social media mentions. Even the occasional in-person recognition suggests Tridion Stack Exchange is being used and making an impact for Tridion-using organizations.

Comment: I tend to agree with most of what you mention, but found one interesting detail that some of the questions did not have an accepted answer yet, so they obviously require more attention (the questions were of good quality though)

Comment: I think we need to keep on encouraging people to come back and accept answers. I suspect some people are not closing the loop (probably due to be being new to Stack Exchange) and are just using the information.